# json parse long double values without auto format

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to parse json array with some values.
Got some problems with long values like that "0.00009800".

I've tried jsonObject.getDouble and getString on it - it returns 9.8E-5.
Also tried BigDecimal with same results.

It should has simple solution which i'm missing.

```
tmp.high24h = Double.valueOf(e.getString("High"));
tmp.low24h = java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(e.getDouble("Low")).doubleValue();
```

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 2):

`9.8E-5` is the expected value. It represents `9.8 * 10^(-5)`.

Comment: If you're parsing to a double, that *is* the value. It's just being represented in your console or REPL with that output string; the formatting is actually irrelevant. If you need to care about the format, you need to convert it back to a string using something like the `toFixed` method.

Answer (score 0):

Always use **String** datatype for larger decimal values. After the conversion of json string to java object, convert it to BigDecimal value by passing the string as an argument in BigDecimal constructor.

Comment: trying both ways - same results
tmp.high24h = Double.valueOf(e.getString("High"));
tmp.low24h=java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(e.getDouble("Low")).doubleValue();

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
tmp.high24h = e.getDouble("High");
String test = String.format(Locale.US, "%.5f", tmp.high24h);
```